# How to calculate term of loan based on their field

Tags: javascript, math, calculator

I have created calculator to find **Term of loan** based on loan amount, Interest rate per annum and Monthly payment.

My Example Data is:

```
Loan amount: 1,000,000
Interest Rate: 1.09
Monthly Payment: 1,500
```

With this example data, my result is 85.39yr(s) and answer is right but when enter **10,000,000.00** i am getting **0.00** result. Why i am getting this result and what's wrong in my code.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

**My Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Term of loan calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#frmCalculate input[type="text"]').on('change', function() {
        var val = this.value;
        val = val.replace(/,/g, "");
        val = number_format(val, 2);
        this.value = val;
    });
});

//function for formatting number with commas
function number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {

    var n = !isFinite( + number) ? 0: +number,
    prec = !isFinite( + decimals) ? 0: Math.abs(decimals),
    sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',': thousands_sep,
    dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.': dec_point,
    s = '',
    toFixedFix = function(n, prec) {
        var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
        return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
    };
    // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
    s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
    if (s[0].length > 3) {
        s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
    }
    if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
        s[1] = s[1] || '';
        s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
    }
    return s.join(dec);
}

function calculate() {

    //Term of loan
    if (frmCalculate.loan_amount.value != "" && frmCalculate.interest_rate.value != "" && frmCalculate.monthly_payment.value != "") {
        var loan_amount = document.getElementById("loan_amount").value;
        loan_amount = loan_amount.replace(/,/g, "");
        var interest_rate = document.getElementById("interest_rate").value;
        interest_rate = interest_rate.replace(/,/g, "");
        var monthly_payment = document.getElementById("monthly_payment").value;
        monthly_payment = monthly_payment.replace(/,/g, "");

        loan_amount = parseFloat(loan_amount.replace(/\s/g, "").replace(",", "."));
        monthly_payment = parseFloat(monthly_payment.replace(/\s/g, "").replace(",", "."));

        rte = interest_rate / 1200;
        pmt = monthly_payment;
        amt = loan_amount;
        yrs = (Math.log(1 + (rte / (pmt / (amt) - rte))) / Math.log(1 + rte)) / 12;
        yrs = yrs * 1000;
        yrs = Math.round(yrs);
        yrs = yrs / 1000;

        document.getElementById('term_value').innerHTML = number_format(yrs, 2);
    }

}
</script>

<form action="#" method="post" id="frmCalculate" name="frmCalculate">
  <div class="user-prf-box">
    <div class="user-prf-inner-bg">
      <!--Loan amount-->
      <div class="mortage-div-row">
        <label class="loan_label" id="lbl_amount" for="loan_amount">
          Loan amount
        </label>
        <span>
          <small class="small">
            S$
          </small>
          <input type="text" onchange="customCheck()" class="nput-calc amount_box" id="loan_amount" name="loan_amount">
          <div id="amount_value">
          </div>
        </span>

      </div>
      <!--Interest rate per annum-->
      <div class="mortage-div-row">
        <label class="lineheight-normal loan_label" id="lbl_interest" for="interest_rate">
          Interest rate per annum
        </label>
        <span style="line-height:25px;">
          <input type="text" maxlength="12" class="input-calc new-input interest_box" id="interest_rate" name="interest_rate" style="display: inline;">
          <span id="interest_value">
          </span>

          <span class="percentage">
            %
          </span>

        </span>

      </div>
      <!--Term of loan-->
      <div class="mortage-div-row">
        <label class="loan_label" id="lbl_term" for="term_loan">
          Term of loan
        </label>
        <span style="line-height:25px;">
          <input type="text" maxlength="12" class="input-calc new-input term_box" id="term_loan" name="term_loan" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled">
          <b><div id="term_value">
          </div></b>
          <span class="yrcs">
            yr(s)
          </span>

        </span>

      </div>
      <!--Monthly payment-->
      <div style="line-height:25px;" class="mortage-div-row">
        <label class="lbl_monthly" id="lbl_monthly_payment">
          Monthly payment
        </label>
        <span class="width-diff">

          <span class="lbl_monthly">
            S$ 
            <span id="monthly_payment_value">
            </span>
            <span id="total">
            </span>
          </span>
          <input type="text" value="" class="input-calc new-input monthly_payment_box" id="monthly_payment" name="monthly_payment" style="display: inline; margin-left: 2px;">
        </span>

      </div>
      <div class="btn-regis-div">
        <input type="button" onclick="calculate();" value="CALCULATE" class="btnsavedrft calculate" name="loancal">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Suggestion: _don't_ use `eval`... ever

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem: Hey thanks for your suggestion. I edited stack code but still i am getting 0.00 result.

Comment: I didn't expect that to solve your problem, but `eval` is probably the worst thing you can do in JS

Comment: @Rajnikanth, `yrs = (Math.log(1 + (rte / (pmt / (amt) - rte))) / Math.log(1 + rte)) / 12;` - This line returns `NaN` in case of 10,000,000.00.

Comment: @theghostofc I got the error. Do you have idea about this?

Comment: You may like to round the input data, specifically `rte` to 2 or 3 decimal places, (whatever works for you)

Answer (score 3):

With a rate of 1.09% and a loan of $1M, the monthly interest is
`1.09/12/100*10^6=908.33`
When the loan is $10M, the monthly interest is $9,083.33.  Since the monthly payment doesn't cover the interest, the balance of the loan grows, and the loan is never repaid.  Your monthly payment must cover the interest accrued, and then some.

Answer (score 2):

You calculation wants Math.log to *sometimes*  calculate a negative number. Since you can take the log of a negative you get an error.

check out the fiddle. I put `console.log` in strategic places. Note that this calculation:

`pmt / (amt) - rte` gives a negative output.

http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/azATg/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I like your response but can you tell me what is the solution for this :)

Comment: You are subtracting %'s  from a number I am not sure what you did there. Sometimes the monthly payment is smaller then the interest rate percentages